# EF Core - create relationship without primary/foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to configure EF to include documents when retriving a user or product. The entity Document has a ReferenceId property which should store either UserId or ProductId. This way, when I save a document for a user or product, the UserId or ProductId is saved to *Document.ReferenceId*.

Entities:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
}
```

Configuring:

```
builder.Entity<User>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    e.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    e.HasMany(e => e.Documents)
     .WithOne()
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});

builder.Entity<Product>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    e.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    e.HasMany(e => e.Documents)
     .WithOne()
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});

builder.Entity<Document>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    e.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    e.ToTable("Documents");
});
```

Saving:

```
var user = new User { };
var userDocument = new Document { ReferenceId = user.Id };

var product = new Product { };
var productDocument = new Document { ReferenceId = product.Id };

_context.Users.Add(user);
_context.Products.Add(product);
_context.Add(userDocument);
_context.Add(productDocument);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Migrations:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Documents",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        ReferenceId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        ProductId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Documents", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Documents_Products_ProductId",
            column: x => x.ProductId,
            principalTable: "Products",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Documents_Users_UserId",
            column: x => x.UserId,
            principalTable: "Users",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

I don't want 2 foreign keys (ProductId and UserId) to be created on Documents table. Is there a way to make EF automatically link UserId and ProductId to ReferenceId?

Comment: Try to imagine what this should look like in pure SQL. One field can't possibly be a FK to multiple tables. This is the infamous *polymorphic associations* (anti) pattern.

Comment: Hi Gert, I agree with you. I don't want to have any FK's. What I want is to find a way (if possible) to make EF automatically map User.Id and Product.Id to Document.ReferenceId (so I don't need to manually assign the values). The same applies when retrieving the records.

Comment: Not sure how you want to create related entities without foreign keys. Having foreign keys doesnt mean you have to manually assign them

Comment: You're practically asking EF to read your mind. Unfortunately, that's not supported.

Comment: You can try by adding [NotMapped] on Documents properties. So you won't see foreign keys on your migration file... I think the easiest way is that, even so, it's not a well DB structure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to solve it would be to have User and Product inherit a base class and move the Id and Documents properties to that class.

```
public class BaseObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseObject
{
}

public class Product : BaseObject
{
}

public class Document
{
    public string BaseObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your answer. This still creates 2 foreign keys (ProductId and UserId) on Documents.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see, is to use TPH inheritance ([See here for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)).

I have quoted and edited the [answer by Erik H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62371567/12892553).

```
public enum DocumentType
{
    User = 0,
    Product = 1
}

public class BaseObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectType DocumentType{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseObject
{
}

public class Product : BaseObject
{
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BaseObjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseObject DocumentObject { get; set; }
}
```

Via fluent-Api you can set a discriminator. This way ef core will only create one table for for both objects `Product` and `User` and distinguishes their type by the value of the discriminator column. But only as long as they have exactly the same properties which they share from the base class. As soon as you add properties to one of those subclasses a new table will be created (with all properties from the base- and subclass).
Here is the configuration for the discriminator:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseObject>()
    .HasDiscriminator<DocumentType>("DocumentType")
    .HasValue<User>(DocumentType.User)
    .HasValue<Product>(DocumentType.Product)
```

This may not be a clean approach (for me it seems like User and Product should not inherit from the same base class, because they do not share anything than the relations to documents). But it should work as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a many to many table:

```
public class Product
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<ProductDocument> ProductDocuments{ get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
  public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDocument
{
  public ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
  public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

You will have to create a separate table for your user table ie `UserDocumentes` using the same pattern.

Comment: Hi Vince, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.